# Yajra DataTable: how to access row data values in addColumn( )

Tags: laravel, eloquent, yajra-datatable

I have set up a Yajra Datatable in my laravel 8 application. I want to access a column value hl_name as $row->hl_name in Confirm message of the addColumn() function as below:

```
->addColumn('action', static function($hosp){
           $btn ='<a href="'.route('HospitalDeleteRoute', $hosp->hl_id).'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="onclick="return confirm('/'Are you sure you want to delete the hospital: {{'.$row->hl_name.'}})>Delete</a>';
                  return $btn;})
```

However this altogether bypass the Confirm Message and execute the deletion. If I change the $row->hl_name to $row->hl_id, the message box successfully appears with the respective Id value. Do I somehow need to notify data to the rows of Datatable? I am displaying my dataTable in the controller as below:

```
public function index(HospitalDataTable $dataTable)
{
       return $dataTable->render('hospitals.index');
}
```

I am NOT initiating my datatable though script as it then gives warning/error:

```
// $('#hospital-table').DataTable({
//     paging: false,
//     searching: false,
//     ordering:  false,
//     lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 500]],
// });
```

uncommenting above gives error

> DataTables warning: table id=hospital-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

The dataTable is successfully implemented as rows of data are shown along with Delete action., and the delete operation is successfully executed. However the confirmation message does not show name of hospital to be deleted.
Following are the main 3 functions of my DataTable class. I would appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

```
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
       return datatables()->eloquent($query)
                        ->addIndexColumn()
                        ->addColumn('action', static function($hosp){
           $btn ='<a href="'.route('HospitalDeleteRoute', $hosp->hl_id).'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="onclick="return confirm('/'Are you sure you want to delete the hospital: {{'.$row->hl_name.'}})>Delete</a>';
                  return $btn;})
                        ->rawColumns(['action']);
     }

    public function query(Hospital $model)
   {
       return $model->newQuery()
                    ->join('district', function($join) {
                       $join->on('district.dt_id', '=', 'hospital.dt_id');
                    })
                    ->join('tehsil', function($join) {
                       $join->on('tehsil.teh_id', '=', 'hospital.teh_id');
                    })
                    ->select('hospital.*', 'district.dt_name', 'tehsil.teh_name');
    }

 public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('hospital-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->orderBy(1);
    }

protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
         Column::make('DT_RowIndex')->title('S/No')->orderable(false)->searchable(false),
         Column::make('hl_name')->title('Hospital Name'),
         Column::make('teh_name')->title('Tehsil'),
         Column::make('dt_name')->title('District'),
         Column::make('Assessment_Status')->title('Assessment Status'),
         Column::computed('action')->title('Action')->exportable(false)->printable(false)->orderable(false)->searchable(false)->width(60)->addClass('text-center')
       
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it came out to be a formatting issue with the commas surrounding the message.

```
$btn ='<a href="'.route('HospitalDeleteRoute', $row->hl_id).'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete the hospital: '.$row->hl_name.'\')">Delete</a>';
```